# Swift 3 Animation: code runs but there is no visual efect

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, fade, fadeout

My animation's code gets executed (I can stop the execution with a breakpoint on any of the animation lines) but I visually see nothing. It even takes the second I set for the duration for doing nothing, it just performs the next segue. My text fields should be fading out in 1 sec.

```
        //animate text fields (fade till dissappear)
        let animationTextFields = {() -> Void in
            self.firstField.alpha = 0.0
            self.secondField.alpha = 0.0
            self.thirdField.alpha = 0.0
            self.fourthField.alpha = 0.0

        }


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: animationTextFields)


        //animate next button (flies right)

        //animate back button (flies left)

        //animate "please" label (flies up)





        self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "SegueToMainNavigation", sender: self)
```

As you can see, I also need further animations, but one step at a time.

Any idea why my animation isn't happening?

Comment: make sure that initial value of textfield's alpha other than zero

Comment: @raki the fields are visible, so it should be 1 right?

Comment: You are going somewhere by segue and you want to see animation from your Current VC. i don't get it bro.

Comment: @elk_cloner simple, I want to see the animation before I go somewhere else

Comment: can you please post the complete method instead of comments like   //animate next button (flies right)

//animate back button (flies left)

 //animate "please" label (flies up)

Comment: @JenJose I haven't written that part jet. I was trying to start by animating the text fields only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the segue after the animation completes..

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: animationTextFields, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "SegueToMainNavigation", sender: self)
    })
```

Comment: I accept this answer because of being the simplest one. Sorry, I had made another mistake and that was the reason it didn't work. Your solution is fine! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to happen at the same time, you can coordinate animations in conjunction with the transition via the `transitionCoordinator`:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: self)

transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.label.alpha = 0         // fade out
    }
}, completion: { context in
    self.label.alpha = 1             // if you want, when done, make it visible again so when you return back here you can see it
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `self.layoutIfNeeded()` inside `animationTextFields` closure.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The viewController doesn't have that function. UIView does, but it didn't help after calling it from the textFields

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3)
{

 self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "SegueToMainNavigation", sender: self)          
}
```

Comment: this one doesn't work either, but you don't even use my closure